# Problem adding child nodes using SPWebConfigModification

Tags: spwebconfigmodification, development

I'm using SPWebConfigModification to update web.config. I've got the following scenario:

```
<configuration>
  <configSection>
    <sectionGroup>
      <childnodes />
    </sectionGroup>     
    <sectionGroup>
      <childnodes />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSection>
</configuration>
```

When I add a new `<sectionGroup>` it adds fine but when I add a childnode to it, the child node is adding to the first `<sectionGroup>` tag. I'm using

> Xpath=configuration/configsection/sectionGroup

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are more then one sectionGroups in the Config..try

configuration/configsection/sectionGroup[index]

or you can select correct sectionGroup by giving name as given below.

configuration/configsection/sectionGroup[@name = 'microsoft.sharepoint.client']

above xPath will return the sectionGroup with name 'Microsoft.sharepoint.client'..

Comment: @sbtahir: Thanks for giving the answer, please mark it as the answer. Thanks :)